# How to put drawable for polyline pattern in Mapbox?

Tags: android, xamarin, mapbox, mapbox-android

Just like for marker where we can put drawable for its icon, such as with Marker's `.SetIcon()`, how to do the same with Mapbox's polyline?

I've searched Google but, CMIIW, seems like there isn't a way to do that yet? Some links I think are related:

1. [Github - Dotted Polyline on Android](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/2812)
2. [Runtime Styling API](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/837)

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, `Polyline` doesn't support custom patterns. What I'd suggest is using `LineLayer` with `PropertyFactory.linePattern()` where you pass ID of an image previously added to the map via `MapboxMap#addImage()`.

[Here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/blob/master/MapboxAndroidDemo/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxandroiddemo/examples/styles/LineLayerActivity.java) is an example activity that uses `LineLayer`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Interesting. I haven't got to inserting drawable yet, but to make the line appeared, I have to applied https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/6240 and change `line-source` to `route`.

Comment: Oh, finally I can attach drawable, following exactly like what you've said: ...with `PropertyFactory.linePattern()` where you pass ID of an image previously added to the map via `MapboxMap#addImage()`. Thank you very much!